# What is the best method to get page load time for a SharePoint site through a console application

Tags: c#, sharepoint, page-load-time

I am trying to create a console application for calculating the page load time for sharePoint site pages. I need both the cached and un-cached page load time.

So far I have tried using **System.Net.WebClient** and **System.Diagnostics.stopwatch** to calculate the page load time. But still I am not sure what is the best approach for doing the same.

**Sample code using WebClient**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string urls = "https://www.google.com/";
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
        //Get uncached data for the first time and next time get data from cache
                if (i == 0)
                    client.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache);
                Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
                stopwatch.Start();// start System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch before downloading url
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Username", "Password", "Domain");
                String result = client.DownloadString(urls);
                stopwatch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} = {1}", urls, stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds));

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to move this over to the Code Review Stack Exchange... unless you have a specific question.

Comment: You can have a complete trace on a website, not a console app. If you want to know more, ping me.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you're really after...

If you just want to do occasional synthetic analysis of first and repeat page load times a private instance of webpagetest.org would probably meet your needs (it's pretty simple to set up)

If you want to know what the real user experience is try boomerang.js or use Site Speedd in Google Analytics